# Iframe reloads and gives double content

Tags: javascript

I changed the content of an HTML5 iframe Tag with a function,
however; the function reloads the whole page, which is an issue, as I am not intending for it to do that. Reloading the page in the iframe tag is duplicating the content. This is being caused because I am using the onload event trigger with the iframe tag. Is there a way to block reload in a function with doc.write => document?

Many thanks

```
iframe.onload = function() { 

function_insert_txt_iframe ...

}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

function_insert_txt_window ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable called `isLoaded` and instantiate it with value false. If the value is true you don't need to reload the page:

```
var isLoaded = true;

iframe.onload = function() { 

    if(!isLoaded) function_insert_txt_iframe ...

}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

    if(!isLoaded)  function_insert_txt_window ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Document.readyState` seems like it might do what you want:

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
  if (event.target.readyState === 'interactive') {
    function_insert_txt_iframe();
  }
  else if (event.target.readyState === 'complete') {
    function_insert_txt_window();
  }
});
```

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState